# Plugin to edit htaccess file

Tags: htaccess, ftp

Is there anyway I can edit my htaccess file without using ftp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

- [WP htaccess Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/) - will let you manually edit your `.htaccess` file
- [All-in-one htaccess Plugin](http://www.adesblog.com/2008/07/29/wp-plugin-all-in-one-htaccess-plugin/) - will let you dynamically create an `.htaccess` file based on which modules/features you want set up

*When all else fails, [turn to Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=wordpress+htaccess+plugin&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) ...*

Comment: I used WP htaccess Control for some quick edits on a setup where I was to lazy to do FTPing on. It just did the job. I used it to manually edit the file but it comes with a lot of presets as well.

Answer (score 2):

Many hosts offer cPanel, which includes a File Manager. You can open the file from there. You may need to check that it's showing hidden file types.

Comment: The problem's that I don't have access to the host either :(

Answer (score 0):

Within the versions of cPanel I am familiar with there is a .htaccess specific editor under the Advanced Tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [AskApache Password Protection](http://www.askapache.com/wordpress/htaccess-password-protect.html) plugin ([Worpress repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/askapache-password-protect/Blockquote)), which, from their site

> adds some serious password protection to your WordPress Blog. Not only does it protect your wp-admin directory, but also your wp-includes, wp-content, plugins, etc. plugins as well.

...

> The plugin is simple, you just choose a username and password and you are done. It writes the .htaccess file, without messing it up. It also encrypts your password and creates the .htpasswd file, as well as setting the correct security-enhanced file permissions on both.